# Node + MySQL [ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306]

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, vue.js

I'm working on a project in Vue, in which I'm connecting to an existing MySQL database using Node.

I've connected successfully, e.g. get the message "Connected to the MySQL Server" from my code to show that it's connected when I run node `connect.js`

---

BUT when I try the next step such as creating a simple select query and displaying the results in the console I get the **"error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"** message.

I've looked at other questions on stack of people having similar issues and the fixes have been

1. Ensure DB is running (it is)
2. add port
3. app socket path
   I've tried these solutions and the error prevails.

   **CONNECT.JS**

   ```
   let mysql = require('mysql');

   let connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: '<myhostname>',
   user: '<myusername>',
   password: '<mypass>',
   database: '<mydb>',
   port: '3306',
   socketPath: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
   })

   connection.connect(function(error){
   if (error){
       return console.error('error: ' + error.message)
   }
   console.log('Connected to the MySQL Server')
   })
   ```

   **SELECT.JS**

   ```
   let mysql = require('mysql')
   let config = require('./connect.js')

   let connection = mysql.createConnection(config)

   let sql = 'SELECT * FROM student'
   connection.query(sql,(error,results,fields) => {
       if(error){
           return console.error('error: ' + error.message)
       }
       console.log(results)
   })
   connection.end()
   ```

Is it something wrong with the `select.js` file? or is it to do with the configuration of the DB?

Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't `connection.end()` have to be inside callback of query?

Comment: `let config = require('./connect.js')`,  did you mean `./config.js` ?

Comment: @jai i took it from here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/select/ changing it makes no difference

Comment: @Jai  mysql queues commands, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Keith as my configuration file is called connect i thought it wouldnt make a difference since it's just a change of variable name? I'm new to this so perhaps youre right

Comment: It depends what's in `connect.js`, do you have a `modules.exports = theConfig` or something like that?  IOW: if you do `console.log(config)` what's it showing.?  If it's the same connect.js you have in your first snippet, then it wont' work.

Comment: @Tom how many logs do you see in the console?

Comment: @Keith all that's in my connect file is what's pasted abouve

Comment: That's why it's not working.. you will find the value of config to be undefined..  you have not exported anything from connect.js,.  you could maybe just do  `module.exports = connection` in the connect.js,  and then `const connection = require("./connect")` in you second script.  You will then not need to createConnection in the second one.

Comment: I gave it a go but it doesnt seem to be working
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/select/
This is what my code is based off using the same filenames etc @Keith

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by including the full connection configuration before the query in the select.js file.